# Bash code to struture proteomics data

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I need help concerning retructuring my dataset so that I can perform the downstream analysis. I am presently dealing with proteomics data and want to perform comparative analysis. The problem is the protein ids. In general one protein can have more then 1 id and they are separated by "`;`". I need to print the entire line of the same protein with different protein ids. for example:-

Input file :

```
        tom dick harry  jan
a;b;c   1     2    3     4
d;e     4     5    7     3
```

desirable output:

```
    tom dick harry jan
a   1   2   3   4
b   1   2   3   4
c   1   2   3   4
d   4   5   7   3
e   4   5   7   3
```

many many thanks in advance

Comment: Why have you tagged this with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{$0="key "$0} {split($1,a,/;/); for (i=1; i in a; i++) { $1=a[i]; print } }' file | column -t
key  tom  dick  harry  jan
a    1    2     3      4
b    1    2     3      4
c    1    2     3      4
d    4    5     7      3
e    4    5     7      3
```

You can trivially remove the word "key" from the output if you don't like it but IMHO having some columns with and some without headers is a very bad idea - just makes any further processing more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. I have tried your suggested code and it worked. The only issue is that the newly generated dataset do splitted the "keys" based on ";" and made a new row, but somehow it failed to print the lines, therefore leaving them as blanks (except the first one). For example: between a;b;c, it only printed for "a" where as b and c though seperated but are blank lines.Your input on this will be beneficial for me. Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your input file. Maybe it was generated on Windows and so contains control-Ms? Try running `dos2unix` or similar on your input file before running UNIX tools on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

read header
printf "%4s %s\n" "" "$header"

while true
do
  read ids values
  for id in $(tr ';' ' ' <<< "$ids")
  do
    printf "%-4s %s\n" "$id" "$values"
  done
done
```

This reads the header and prints is (just slightly differently formatted), then it reads each line and prints for each of these a bunch of lines, one line for each `id` given in the beginning of the line.  For finding the `id`s, the `ids` string is split over semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice to understand some of the reasons not to do this.

Comment: All the reasoning given there was already known to me, and still I find that loop approach is the best solution in this case.  Often a perfect solution which does also things like handling nullbytes (which aren't supposed to be in the input at all) or which is performant like machinecode is not the best solution for a concrete problem at hand.  Implementation time often is the most valuabe aspect.  Unless a similarly small solution is presented, I stick to mine.

Comment: wrt `Unless a similarly small solution is presented, I stick to mine` - [the solution I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47931005/1745001) is briefer, more portable, more robust, easier to enhance and will run orders of magnitude faster.